# Como redirecionar para a página de login após um determinado tempo ocioso em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, session

Como o título da pergunta diz gostaria que a um tempo determinado onde o usuário se encontra ocioso, e assim o sistema destrua a sessão e redirecione automaticamente para a página de login. Eu sei que o php possui a função session_cache_expire() (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php). Porém pelo que entendi este tempo é independente do usuário estar ocioso, além do que ao terminar o tempo a sessão só ira ser destruída quando houver a requisição da página. Acredito que muitos aqui já tiveram a experiência desagradável de preencher um formulário extenso e ao enviar o submit perder os dados devido ao tempo gasto preenchendo o formulário (eu tive preenchendo os dados para inscrição do ENEM no celular). Preferiria utilizar apenas PHP, mas acho que será necessário utilizar javascrpit também. Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Esse exemplo do Enem é programação porca (e programação porca é o que mais tem, em especial na coisa pública). Um sistema decente manteria os dados do form, mesmo a sessão acabada, e te permitiria relogar pra continuar, num caso mais extremo. Pode ter algum tonto que não entenda de PHP e vai te falar pra aumentar o tempo de sessão, mas só mudaria o problema de lugar (além de não ser o jeito certo de se usar sessão). O ideal é pensar em como armazenar esse form, independente da sessão, e permitir o usuário continuar de onde parou (isso vale pra qualquer tipo de dado, não apenas para esse caso).

Comment: Em outras palavras, é muito bom que você esteja se preocupando com isso, mas não existe receita mágica que resolva com simplicidade. Sessão é pra ser uma ferramenta auxiliar. Tudo que precisa demorar bastante, pode ser gerenciado de maneiras mais complexas. Por exemplo, é muito mais limpo relogar o usuário automaticamente e de maneira transparente do que encompridar a sessão. Nesse caso o cookie avulso e o login não destrutivo (aceitar o form de qualquer jeito, mas pedir login pra prosseguir) tem menos efeitos colaterais.

Comment: Sobre usar JS, uma maneira seria um script ficar renovando a sessão junto do PHP, mas se nesse meio tempo há uma pequena falha de conexão, pode ter o problema da mesma forma. Outra idéia seria usar o JS para além de resolver o problema com PHP, você ter um cache local do form preenchido (e descartar depois de um tempo razoável sem uso, claro, seja em JS, seja em PHP). Qualquer caminho que escolher, vai precisar um pouco de raciocinio e capricho, mas afinal, programar é exatamente isso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte maneira,

**1** - O usuário fez login
(cria-se uma tabela temporária no db, gravando um registro contendo a data e tempo)

**2** - Um javascript é iniciado como objetivo de realizar requisições get a esta tabela temporaria verificando o registro de data e tempo que consta nela e confrontando com data e tempo da requisição, este javascript deve ser executado em intervalos de XX minutos.

**3** - O usuário faz uma ação carrega uma pagina por ex:
(atualiza o registro regravando data e tempo) - o JavaScript continua sua rotina

**4** - O usuário fica sem realizar ação por um tempo - o javascript em algum momento irá confrontar os dados e dai sim, quando o tempo de comparação for maior que o estipulado (tempo ocioso permitido), o javascript acionado um php que irá destruir a tabela temporaria e enviar o usuario a tela de login novamente.

utilizo desta forma em um sistema que desenvolvi.